# Got Error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' with negative look behind regex (?<!(Log\())@"[^"]+"

Tags: regex, xcode, bash, shell, grep

I want to find all hardcoded strings in my project except words starts with `Log(`.

Using this regex to do so but getting an error as mentioned above.

```
KEYWORDS='(?<!(Log\())@"[^"]+"'

find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" \) -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename "($KEYWORDS).*\$
```

Is there any other alternative regex or script to get the same result.

Comment: That's a Perl regex, not an (egrep) extended regex. I suspect the answer is "no" since you're talking about xcode, but does your grep have the `-P` option?

Comment: no it don't have -P option. is there a way I can use awk to get the same output

Comment: As far as I know, only Perl regex engine has implemented negative look-behind.

Comment: Please show some sample input and output

Answer (score 1):

You might just filter out what you don't want to see:

```
xargs -0 grep -EH '@"[^"]+"' | grep -v 'LOG\(@"'
```

If you want to stick with your regular expression:

```
xargs -0 perl -ne 'print "$ARGV: $_" if /(?<!LOG\()@".+?"/'
```

Comment: As a Canadian, that grep invocation amuses me.

Comment: thanks!! second one gives me results almost close to what I need.

Comment: and how can I print only the matches?. the above perl script gives me entire line as o/p

Comment: `perl -ne 'print "$ARGV: $1" if /(?<!LOG\()(@".+?")/'`